# Eloquera with ASP.NET MVC. Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, object-oriented-database, eloquera

I am curious about using an object db so thought i'd give Eloquera a go.

I am having problems getting it running unfortunately. (running in "desktop mode")

I have done these steps as directed:

1) Copy the following assemblies and a configuration file from the %ProgramFiles%\Eloquera folder into a project folder:
Eloquera.config
Eloquera.Client.dll
Eloquera.Common.dll
Eloquera.Server.exe

You can copy the reference files into a separate folder for your convenience.

2) Uninstall the Eloquera DB (sounds awful, but we have copies all files we will need) - **(I never installed it)**

3) Add Eloquera.config into your project via “Add an existing item…”, and set its "Copy to Output Directory" property to "Copy Always". **Done**

4) Add the project references to these files:
Eloquera.Client.dll   **yep**
Eloquera.Server.exe   **yep**

5) Rebuild your project and check that Debug\ and/or Release\ folders contain the following files along with your application:
Eloquera.config
Eloquera.Client.dll
Eloquera.Common.dll
Eloquera.Server.exe
**It does**

6) You may change a physical path to the database files in the Eloquera.config file by setting DatabasePath value:

DatabasePath="c:\dev\db" **I did this also**

The error i get is this:

```
The connection to the server (local) on the port 43962 cannot be established.

The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
```

Weirdly, changing ServerPort to something else in the config does not change this error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think this mode is not supported.

You are meant to use Client / Server mode, which is a shame cause i was hoping i could use this desktop method to deploy into a shared host.

No dice.

Answer (score 0):

You can download from Eloquera website desktop project that is already configured and working and can be used as a base.

Comment: Eloquera DB suppports both desktop and C/S modes. For C/S mode use installations provided on website, for desktop there is DesktopProject.zip on Download page.

Comment: Pretty much idea is, you need to have Common, Client dlls, Server exe and Eloquera config in the the same folder. You can put them in the same bin folder where application is. To do so, you need to add all these and select Copy Always for Eloquera.config (add Eloquera.config also to the project). That's it. But if you are a starter you can simply download DesktopProject.zip from the Eloquera Download page.

Comment: As far as i can tell, the "Desktop project" is a .cs program that runs locally, the project i am making is an ASP.NET project that runs through a web-server.

Comment: In this case you need client-server.
And you should not use (local) but something like
DB("server=localhost;password=;options=none;"); 

Run server e.g. localhost (if you don't want to install server, copy Eloquera.config, Eloquera.Server.exe, Eloquera.Common.dll, Eloquera.Client.dll into one folder and then start Eloquera.Server.exe)

Add Eloquera.Client.dll, Eloquera.Common.dll to your project and run it. To distribute you need only those 2 libs.

Answer (score 0):

Kohan,

Desktop mode is supported in Eloquera, otherwise my application would not work. :-) There is a good start-up project for the desktop application on the Eloquera web site, have a look at that.

Comment: I got the desktop app working, but when i plugged everything into a web project it would fail.

Answer (score 0):

I get this issue with VS2010 and 64 bit Windows 7 - if you are using the 32 bit dlls (as we are as our app needs to work on 32/64) then make sure your target build (in VS) is set to 32 bit rather than AnyCPU.

I still cannot get the Database browser working but the code is working now.

Also - obvious things like make sure your firewall is turned off etc. make sure you can telnet onto the port