# asp.net : How to embed a server.exe?

Tags: asp.net

I haven't put up a web site/app yet, so please excuse my ignorance.

Eloquera looks like a great object database, but the embedded (in-process) mode is not meant to be used for a web app. I have to therefore somehow run the server exe on the server to use it.

When I use the server on my comp it first needs to be allowed through the firewall, as one would expect.

I am wondering if I could somehow run the server.exe in the same process as the web app and still have it be a tcp/ip server accepting multiple connections.

Or perhaps there are normal ways of dealing with this situation on typical "retail" web hosts?

**In Short: I believe I am trying to embedd a tcp "server.exe" into an asp.net web application**

Comment: Why do you need to run this so closely coupled with your ASP.NET application??

Comment: Also see [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4875517/66849)

Comment: Shark, I have no idea if it would be allow to install a windows service on an inexpensive commercial host's machine. And then there is the potential simplicity embedding the DBMS.

Comment: Adding to my last answer: using this database as client/server would involve getting VPS hosting or dedicated hosting -- more expensive and only necessary because of my choice of DB.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the usual thing to do in this situation would be to get a dedicated server, or, more realistically in my case, a VPS (I did say I was learning!).This really pushes up the costs and hassle.  No shared hosting that I can see offers Eloquera DB.

So, it seems that my only option would be a low-end VPS.

It's disappointing that I can't use embedded (desktop mode) eloquera in an asp.net web app, but I understand that this is to do with the nature of web apps.